# Using Classes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to write better more easy to read code and Ive begun starting to use classes..
Confusing thus far, but I can see the positives..
That said im simply trying to merge 2 dataframes...

Previously I've achieved this by using...

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'path/to/file.xlsx'

df  = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet2')

df3 = df.merge(df2, how = 'left, on = 'column1')
```

Trying to implement using classes I have this thus far. Which could be incorrect.....?

```
import pandas as pd 

path = 'path/to/file.xlsx'

class CreateOpFile:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet1')
        self.df2 = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet2')

    def MergeDataFrames(self):
        pd.merge(self.df, self.df2, how = 'left', on= 'column1')
```

So im confused as to how I create a new variable, lets say `df3` outside of the class `CreateOpFile` as I have done using `df3 = df.merge(df2, how = 'left, on = 'column1')` in the first method ?

Comment: its not clear, either you assign it in class or return it from class

Comment: You can directly use `pd.read_excel("path", sheet_name=["sheet1", "sheet2"])` returned output would be dict with two dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to return the new, merged df and assign it to the df3 outside of the class.

```py
import pandas as pd 

path = 'path/to/file.xlsx'

class CreateOpFile:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet1')
        self.df2 = pd.read_excel(path, 'sheet2')

    def MergeDataFrames(self):
        return pd.merge(self.df, self.df2, how = 'left', on= 'column1')

df3 = CreateOpFile(path).MergeDataFrames()
```

Btw, according to the naming conventions mentioned in [PEP-8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/), method names should consist of lowercase letters and underscores to separate words. Therefore `merge_data_frames()` seems to be a better naming.